# Is it possible to include a hyperlink in a Facebook wall post?

Tags: facebook

I want to turn a word in my Facebook wall post into a hyperlink, like [this](http://example.com/). As far as I can tell, your only options as to include the plain text of the link in your post, or "attach" the link to the bottom of your post. Neither is a good solution for me, I want to link from specific words (so I can say things like "Go [here](http://example.com/) for foo.").

Is this possible to do on my Facebook wall? I know that it is possible in "Notes", using html-style tags (`<a href="http://example.com/">foo</a>`), but this doesn't work on my wall.

Comment: How would you "attach it"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot. You are asking about using the [Links](http://www.facebook.com/posted.php) feature within the publisher so this will appear in your Links section.

> The ability to embed HTML using the
>   Links application is not currently
>   available.

http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=14486

I think you are going the right way with Notes (especially for long messages). Abuse the [CheatSheet](http://www.facebook.com/notes/phwd/facebook-notes-cheat-sheet/307472899342741). If you are publishing to all your friends, this should appear in your friends' News Feed.

[image: Cheat Sheet]

I have seen my friend use the [Advanced Wal](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=3118555174)l application. From what I remember it looked like it worked but like <strike>all</strike> most publishing applications ended up being prone to sending spam. You also have to be aware that once a friend blocks/hides an application for one friend , it is applicable to all.

A second way I would recommend is to shorten your links with [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) or other url shortening services. So your above example would be,

> "Go http//bit.ly/xxyy for foo."

At least you can shorten long links here. Additionally the Publisher allows one link to be *featured* under your post, so if you want something to stand out, click the `X` next to the featured link to traverse through all the links in your update.

A third way I used to do sometimes especially if there is an entity on Facebook that already represents the website is to use the `@` mention feature.

Comment: Your link "Advanced wall" doesnt already work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put HTML on your Facebook wall, but there are [apps you can install that will let you do this](http://www.whatapps.com/2007/11/27/the-12-walls-of-facebook-part-1/). Use with caution! Has anyone used these?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook apparently introduced this at some point, though for now, the only way I know to do it is a bit of a kludge.

1. Write the text in a rich text editor such as Google Docs.
2. Attach a hyperlink where desired by selecting the text and hitting control-K or equivalent, then by pasting or typing the destination URL.
3. Copy the rich text to your clipboard.
4. Paste into your Facebook post.