# How is it possible to post named hyperlinks in a facebook post?

Tags: facebook, links

[This post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/is-it-possible-to-include-a-hyperlink-in-a-facebook-wall-post) has asked a similar question, but I don't want to know if it IS possible (because I already know it is), but HOW is it possible. For example, you can go to [this facebook link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/702948280457974/permalink/702948483791287/), which is a permalink to a public facebook post, and it contains a hyperlink that leads to https://www.google.com, for example.

When you type hyperlinks into Microsoft Word, and then paste it in a facebook post, it initially shows up as plain text while editing. However, after posting it suddenly becomes a working hyperlink. This does not seem to work when pasting hyperlinks copied from the web, for example.

How come a plain text becomes a working hyperlink? Is this method reproducible with other devices? Why Microsoft Word?

——-

UPDATE

Today I realized that the instructions cited above don’t work anymore. Facebook must have updated its posts configuration, and where there was a named hyperlink, now there is a Markdownish structure like

```
[text](www.hyperlink.com)
```

Comment: This question is about similar issue - but at the moment, there are no answers: [Can I turn/disguise links as texts in Facebook posts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154420)