# Can I turn/disguise links as texts in Facebook posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, links, embed

I oftentimes post links in comment sections and Facebook Groups, to direct a person to a post, a group or a website. But sometimes links take too much space and they're kind of a bit too messy to look at, that's why sometimes they seem not very engaging. I always wanted to fix that problem, To post a clear message that directs other people to a website, a post, or a group. But there aren't Much sites and resources that tackles this dilemma. I found several references that talks about this matter. But they don't seem to provide sufficient information, some of them doesn't work.

How do I achieve this?